# Need some tips for my application

Tags: c#, winforms, windows

I'm doing an exchanger application and I need help to combine the amount I have put in, in the textBox and the currency in the combobox to another textBox when I click on the Assign/Add button.

I have been stuck with this for while now.

I have tried many things, maybe I'm overthinking the problem.

```
private void asignBttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Currency currency1 = valueFromCoBox.SelectedItem as Currency;

    if (valueFromCoBox.Text == string.Empty) { return; }

    foreach (var item in resultBox.Text)
    {

    }
```

Comment: You are trying to take text from two different sources and concatenate them into another text box?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand what is the type `Currency` that you pull from the select box (I'm not really familiar with the .net type).

But if it is a custom class it'll be easier.

```
private void asignBttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Currency currency1 = valueFromCoBox.SelectedItem as Currency;

    if (valueFromCoBox.Text == string.Empty) { return; }

    //// how about this?
    resultBox.Text = valueFromCoBox.Text + currency1;
```

Let us know.

Comment: Why do you assume that `Currency` can be concatenated with a `string`?

Comment: Because It would be great if it can be :) Otherwise I'll work something out.